# PL/SQL Creating Trigger In A Package

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, triggers, package

I have written a PL/SQL package that has all my application code operating on the tables in the hr schema. I wanted to write a trigger that fires in response to any DML statements being executed on the employee table.

**Can you write a trigger in a PL/SQL package ?** . I mean you can write everything within a packge so technically one should be able to write a trigger within a packge.

I know I can create this trigger as database object too. **But i want this trigger to be within the scope of the package .**

**Is it possible to have the trigger fire "only" in response to DML statements executed by the package code ?**

Appreciate your comments / suggestions !!!

Comment: This is all answered in the manual.

Comment: which manual ??? Could you please point it out.

Comment: The Oracle manual. If you are serious about using Oracle, you should have a bookmark for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your trigger's code to only run if the DML was initiated by your package, the way I'd do it is to have a global boolean in your package, e.g.

```
my_pkg_running boolean := FALSE;
```

In your package, wrap your DML with:

```
my_pkg_running := TRUE;
... execute the DML here ...
my_pkg_running := FALSE;
```

Your trigger should then call a package procedure, e.g.

```
my_pkg.trigger_fired;
```

Which would have code like this:

```
PROCEDURE trigger_fired IS
BEGIN
  IF my_pkg_running THEN
     ... your trigger code ...
  END IF;
END trigger_fired;
```

This way, if the trigger is fired from DML that did not originate from the package, the `trigger_fired` procedure will simply do nothing.

Comment: This is interesting. I didn't think of this. Will try it

Answer (score 4):

A trigger is a separate database object from a package, and there is no direct way to have a piece of code in a package executed when a triggering action such as `BEFORE UPDATE ON xxxx` or `AFTER INSERT ON yyyy` occurs. You can, of course, code your triggers in such a manner that they call packaged routines, similar to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TRIGGER_PACKAGE AS
  PROCEDURE MY_TRIGGER_PROC;
END TRIGGER_PACKAGE;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TRIGGER_PACKAGE AS
  PROCEDURE MY_TRIGGER_PROC IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TRIGGER_PACKAGE.MY_TRIGGER_PROC invoked');
  END MY_TRIGGER_PROC;
END trigger_package;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MY_TABLE_AIUD
  AFTER INSERT UPDATE DELETE ON MY_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  TRIGGER_PACKAGE.MY_TRIGGER_PROC;
END MY_TABLE_AIUD;
```

However, by doing so your lose access to the :NEW and :OLD values, and don't have a way to determine how/why the trigger was invoked (e.g. the INSERTING, UPDATING, and DELETING booleans), and thus I can't recommend this as a way to implement triggers. YMMV.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

No, it snot possible to write triggers within a package. Although you can call implemented part of a package from a trigger